# I dont know how to add material on single faces

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

[image]

From cube enter *Edit Mode* At Center => then dupliacate 4 times => press <kbd>F</kbd>, but then how to add imported image (texture) to this face i created.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to enable *Images as Planes* addon which comes by default with Blender.

[image]

With this you can open an image and it will import itself onto a 3D plane.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but i'm already know about images as planes.
all i want to know is it possible to add images from method i mention before?